# Use lower-case constants for false, true, null in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, constants, lowercase, uppercase

There is any way to set them in auto completion code in lowercase? Automatically they appear in UPPERCASE, I know that constants are defined in UPPERCASE but I prefer lowercase for them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the next in **C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9.1\php\phpstubs\phpruntime\Core.php**

```
define ('LOG_PERROR', 32);
define ('TRUE', true);
define ('FALSE', false);
define ('NULL', null);
define ('ZEND_THREAD_SAFE', false);
define ('ZEND_DEBUG_BUILD', false);
```

to

```
define ('LOG_PERROR', 32);
//define ('TRUE', true);
//define ('FALSE', false);
//define ('NULL', null);
define ('ZEND_THREAD_SAFE', false);
define ('ZEND_DEBUG_BUILD', false);
```

Comment some "define" and delete netbeans cache at: %USERS%.netbeans\6.9\var\cache\

Comment: On the Mac, the path to this file is /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ [VERSION].app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/phpstubs/phpruntime and the 3 constants to change are around line 1482

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did when I wanted my auto complete to be [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) compliant.

I am using NetBeans 7.3 and Windows 7.

Open this file in your text editor of choice:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3\phpstubs\phpruntime\Core.php

Search for this code:

```
define ('TRUE', true);
define ('FALSE', false);
define ('NULL', null);
```

If you don't care about auto complete, just comment out those 3 lines:

```
// define ('TRUE', true);
// define ('FALSE', false);
// define ('NULL', null);
```

If you want autocomplete to work and use lowercase, change the constants to lowercase:

```
define ('true', true);
define ('false', false);
define ('null', null);
```

Restart NetBeans and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow [PSR-2](https://github.com/bocharsky-bw/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#25-keywords-and-truefalsenull) coding style formatting for lowercase `true`, `false` and `null` constants in `NetBeans` `7.x`/`8.x` at `Ubuntu` you need in: **/home/user/netbeans-8.0/php/phpstubs/phpruntime/Core.php** file (or at `Windows` in: **C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\php\phpstubs\phpruntime\Core.php**) find next lines:

```
define ('TRUE', true);
define ('FALSE', false);
define ('NULL', null);
```

and change to:

```
define ('true', true);
define ('false', false);
define ('null', null);
```

Thereafter not necessary to restart your `NetBeans`, it must work straight. But if it not work, try to restart.

Comment: On the Mac, the path to this file is /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ [VERSION].app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/phpstubs/phpruntime and the 3 constants to change are around line 1482